# JHipster + MongoDB connection

Tags: mongodb, entity, jhipster

I' trying to create a JHipster entity and when I do `mvn spring-boot:run` I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongeez.Mongeez]: Factory method 'mongeez' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 15 more 
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription(DBTCPConnector.java:396)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getType(DBTCPConnector.java:569)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.createServerSelector(DBTCPConnector.java:552)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$100(DBTCPConnector.java:39)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:451)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:409)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.update(DBCollectionImpl.java:263)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:191)
    at org.mongeez.dao.MongeezDao.addTypeToUntypedRecords(MongeezDao.java:56)
    at org.mongeez.dao.MongeezDao.configure(MongeezDao.java:47)
    at org.mongeez.dao.MongeezDao.<init>(MongeezDao.java:43)
    at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.<init>(ChangeSetExecutor.java:36)
    at org.mongeez.Mongeez.process(Mongeez.java:40)
    at com.openmindtech.cm.config.DatabaseConfiguration.mongeez(DatabaseConfiguration.java:78)
    at com.openmindtech.cm.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c5b7ddda.CGLIB$mongeez$1(<generated>)
    at com.openmindtech.cm.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c5b7ddda$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$976221f9.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at com.openmindtech.cm.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c5b7ddda.mongeez(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 16 more
```

I think it's about connection of MongoDB but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a "connection refused", did you start MongoDB?

Comment: How can i start it ? it's not starting when doining mvn spring-boot:run ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicit initialize MongoDB, with `mongod` for example.

After that, you can run `mvn spring-boot:run` and you should be successful.